# After upgrade from bionic to Focal LTS many ppa disabled

Tags: ppa

I have a question of understanding. After upgrade to 20.04 LTS many items under /etc/apt/sources.list.d  were disabled.

For example firefox.Nevertheless (luckily) I get the  latest firefox updates. How does that work?

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
deb-src 

http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
deb

http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa/ubuntu bionic main`
```

Comment: Keeping PPAs from an old version of Ubuntu can cause many problems because of conflicts with the new versions of program libraries and application programs. Generally PPAs should be disabled before upgrading and after successful upgrade you should check if there are (new) versions for the new version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

**That PPA is for testing only**. In fact, the PPA description states:

> Unless you are testing updates, you should NOT install packages from this PPA.

**Disabling PPAs during a release-upgrade is normal**. PPAs are NOT the supported Ubuntu Repositories, and some PPAs can introduce version conflicts with newer software. A normal (human) admin task after a release-upgrade is scrubbing the PPAs to see which (if any) are still needed...and are available in the new release. Your system WON'T make those checks for you.

**Specifically about Firefox**: The Ubuntu Desktop Team and Ubuntu Security Team regularly push Firefox updates through the -security pocket of the Ubuntu repositories, not the PPA.

- Using the -security pocket means that most users automatically get the updated browser without being prompted (and often without even noticing) via Unattended Upgrades.
- Firefox is one of the very few applications that gets new releases pushed to older releases of Ubuntu. This is a security-based exception to normal Ubuntu policy. All supported releases of Ubuntu get the newest Firefox.

  Let's take a look at Firefox on 18.04. You can see that 18.04 shipped with FF 59, but updated 18.04 systems run FF 83

  ```
  $ rmadison firefox | grep bionic
  firefox | 59.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1         | bionic           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el
  firefox | 83.0+build2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2   | bionic-security  | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
  firefox | 83.0+build2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2   | bionic-updates   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
  ```

Comment: Thanks, now it is more understandable. But how can I check which Software will be updatet through the -security pocket of the Ubuntu repositories an which not?

Comment: @ClausNeumayer that question seems unrelated to what you originally asked. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ#How_are_the_.22-updates.22_and_.22-security.22_pockets_different.3F for a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, The `PPA`s you mentioned above belong to `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` (Bionic Beaver).

When you upgraded to `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` (Focal Fossa) they were disabled as they were no longer needed by the system (unless you want to force it). The new `PPA`s of `Focal Fossa` were added during the upgrade process which contains the updated list of software (in repositories).

If you really want to use the previous ones you can manually enable them. **However, I won't suggest you to do that because it can cause collisions between the new and old versions of the software that you want to use.**

**P.S.** If you are a **newbie**, I highly recommend you not to mess up with the `sources.list` file as it can lead to undesirable consequences.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer and information. How can I see what is in the current list of software (repository). What I posted is not soures.lst but file under soures.list.d

Comment: Open `Software and Updates` and select `Other Software` tab. Here, you can see all available `PPA`s (including the disabled ones).